# jupyter notebook and .tabset tabset

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, jupyter, knitr

I like to do adhoc R dev/reports/EDA in notebooks due to separate execution of cells. Once the notebook is in a good shape I transform it directly to html (download as using also nbextensions). A notebook obviously has markdown cells. However, when I use markdown containing:

```
.tabset
```

as described [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-tabs.html) the markdown is not transformed into tabs in the html. Is there a way to still get the tabs or do I always have to go the more cumbersome route:

```
notebook -> markdown -> html
```

I hope this makes sense?

Btw, maybe it has to do with the fact that the above is rmarkdown and not markdown? Maybe I could use a knitr command to pick up the notebook and transform?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using knitr in te final step (markdown -> html)?

Comment: No not yet. I basically use the "download with toc (.html)" option of the notebook. I think the issue is that the notebook goes via markdown and not rmarkdown. So either there is a nice pluging or I have to use knitr to go notebook -> markdown -> rmarkdown -> html. I can download notebook a markdown but then pictures are not embedded and I have to manually rename .md to .rmd and then go to html. this is a pain.

Comment: You could use a script like this: https://github.com/krassowski/complex-upset/blob/a70113ad7520afa8885eb4da49f2d3ab72426c20/scripts/document.sh#L9-L16

Comment: @krassowski thanks not 100% sure what this does but I also use windows - sorry